# needs a good Latin quote to caption magazine to mark my father in law's 100 birthday

Tags: idiom, motto

my father in law who turns 100 is a lover of latin phrases . So we were looking to caption the magazine to mark the occasion. The phrase should signify a life well spent or lived or similar  Do you know of any other phrases which can be used in this instance ?
Some suggested ones are

1. vita quae bene vivitur ,
2. Vita Vitalis  OR
3. Ad multos annos’

much appreciated for your advice please
. many thanks

Comment: *Ad multos annos* is indeed a traditional toast, but I'm not sure I'd use it for a centenary... in my opinion, if you really want to say "A life well lived," and you want to say it in Latin, cnread's answer to your other question is your best bet.

Comment: This question would be better served if you just edited it into your original, especially since, as Sebastian points out, you have a good answer for it.